# Holomorphic function$f: D \to D$ with $f(\frac{1}{2}) =-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f '(\frac{1}{4}) =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analyticity, analytic-functions

Does there exist a holomorphic function$f: D \to D$ with $f(\frac{1}{2}) =-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f '(\frac{1}{4}) =1$ where $ D= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$.

I cannot use any of Schwarz lemma or  Schwarz-Pick theorem here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean ho$\color{red}{\mathrm l}$omorphic?

Comment: It's holomorphic, not homomorphic.

Comment: i made a mistake while caluclation, that's why i deleted the comment

Comment: f(-0.8)=-1.8 :( Why are you not allowed to use the Schwaz Lemma?

Comment: Find two Möbius maps, one sending 0 to 1/2 and one sending -1/2 to 0. Compose them with f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We apply Schwarz-Pick twice - let $f(\frac{1}{4})=a$

$1=|f'(\frac{1}{4})| \le \frac{1-|a|^2}{1-\frac{1}{16}}$ means $|a| \le \frac{1}{4}$

$|\frac{f(1/2)-f(1/4)}{1-\bar f(1/2) f(1/4)}| \le \frac{1/2-1/4}{1-1/8}$ means

$|\frac{2a+1}{a+2}| \le  \frac{2}{7}$

But $|\frac{2a+1}{a+2}| = |2-\frac{3}{a+2}| \ge 2-\frac{3}{|a+2|} \ge 2-\frac{12}{7}=\frac{2}{7}$ means that we must have equality in Schwarz-Pick both times, so $a=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $f$ is a Mobius transform and by inspection $f(z)=-z$ (or noting that any Mobius transform cannot have more than one fixed point inside the unit disc unless it is the identity and $-f$ has two such), but then $f'=-1$ so contradiction!

(assume we have equality in $|2-\frac{3}{a+2}| \ge 2-\frac{3}{|a+2|} \ge 2-\frac{12}{7}=\frac{2}{7}$; it follows from the last inequality that $-\frac{3}{|a+2|}=-\frac{12}{7}$ which means $|a+2|=7/4$; the triangle inequality $|2+a| \ge 2-|a| \ge 7/4$ must be an equality, so $2,a$ must be opposite, hence $a$ is a negative real)

(quick proof that a Mobius automorphism of the disc $g(z)=\gamma \frac{z-c}{1-\bar c z}, |\gamma|=1$ with two fixed points inside the disc is the identity: $g(z)=z$ means $z-\bar c z^2=\gamma (z-c)$; if $c=0, g(z)= \gamma z$ and that has only $0$ as fixed point unless $\gamma=1$; if $c \ne 0$ we get a quadratic with the product of roots having absolute value $|\gamma \frac{c}{\bar c}|=1$ by Viete, hence if a root has $|z_1| <1$ the other must have $|z_2| >1$)

Hence there is no such $f$

Comment: @Conard How do you get $\frac{12}{7}$?

Comment: The minimum of $2-\frac{3}{|a+2|}$ is attained at the maximum of $\frac{3}{|a+2|}$, hence the minimum of $|a+2|$ hence at $a=-1/4$ ($|a| \le 1/4$ by previous arguments); that gives $a+2=7/4, 3/|a+2|=12/7$